# How do I create a link that opens up a new window with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html, hyperlink

I'm currently attempting to create a link like this one:

```
<a href="http://www.mymra.com" onClick="mywindow=window.open('http://www.mymra.com','mywindow','toolbar=yes,location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=900,height=600'); return false;">Motorcycle Insurance</a></li>
```

in PHP. I've attempted to do so with a link in one of my php files, however I can't get it to work correctly, nor load without any errors.

This is the code I've been working with:

```
        echo '
  <a href="'.$ad_link.'" onClick="javascript: pageTracker._trackPageview(\'/outgoing/'.$ga_link.'\'); mywindow=window.open('.$ad_link.');" target=\"_blank\" title="'.$ad_alt.'"'.$ad_target.'>
  <img src="http://'.$ad_image.'" border="0" alt="'.$ad_alt.'" width="150px" height="150px" /></a>';
```

I'm curious as to what I need to do to get the link to work.

I've already tried:

- Copy and pasting the code exactly. (with the exception of editing the links)
- Snipping the code over, taking out anything I thought could cause an error.
- Re-assembling the code to make it work.

I'm unable to create a solution myself, so I'm turning to the community. If anyone could at least lead me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

The php code snippet I provided above is not necessary. I just need an example piece of code to work with.

Thank you for helping me!

I've attempted to use:

```
echo '
<a href="'.$ad_link.'" onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview(\'/outgoing/'.$ga_link.'\'); mywindow=window.open('.$ad_link.'); return false;" target=\"_blank\" title="'.$ad_alt.'"'.$ad_target.'>
<img src="http://'.$ad_image.'" border="0" alt="'.$ad_alt.'" width="150px" height="150px" /></a>';
```

However it then treats the // after http: as a comment tag instead of an addition to http: This was one of my problems previously.

I'm also looking for a lightbox, however for future reference I need help answering this.

Comment: So view it in the HTML and see what it actually looks like

Comment: I suggest you avoid `window.open` as much as possible because it's the very first thing pop-up blockers will prevent. Is `target=_blank` not enough? Maybe an iframe in a modal dialog should do...

Comment: @Mark in HTML the link works fine, it's the PHP link that won't work.

Comment: @elclanrs It's not my choice, it's my employers! target=_blank only opens it in a new tab, not a new window like he wants.

Comment: I mean, compare the link in the HTML that is generated by your PHP with a link in standard HTML that you know works, and note the differences

Comment: Opening things in new windows is no good for usability plus your content won't be delivered to all those users that have ad-blockers. If employer wants a "window", I'd use a modal dialog. There are hundreds of lightbox plugins out there.

Comment: The difference is the html link opens in a window by itself, and my PHP link is only opening in a new tab.

Comment: there is no php 'link' you are simply using php to echo html

Comment: @Dagon As my comment below states, it treats everything after // as a comment tag, rather than as an addition to http:.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
  echo '
  <a href="'.$ad_link.'" onclick="pageTracker._trackPageview(\'/outgoing/'.$ga_link.'\'); mywindow=window.open('.$ad_link.'); return false;" target=\"_blank\" title="'.$ad_alt.'"'.$ad_target.'>
  <img src="http://'.$ad_image.'" border="0" alt="'.$ad_alt.'" width="150px" height="150px" /></a>';
```

I don't know what `$ad_target` is supposed to contain and therefore if it can be placed there, anyway: starting `onclick` with `javascript:` is incorrect, and furthermore you lack `return false;` at the end of the `onlick`.

Try to view echoed html and check for errors in there, any js console (i.e. from Chrome or Firebug) may be helpful as well.

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately. It doesn't echo correctly, instead it treats // as a comment tag, rather than an addition to http:.

Comment: try using " instead of ' in echo. or alternatively printing html and echoing out only variables (`<?=` if you have short tags on).